# AWS CDK: Invalid ARN for CloudWatch Logs when using LogGroup.log_group_arn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to set up a route53.HostedZone with a query logs group in CDK (Python).

The query group is defined as:

```
queryLogGroup = logs.LogGroup(self, 'logGroup',
                                log_group_name='/aws/route53/'+subdomain,
                                retention=logs.RetentionDays.THREE_DAYS,
                                removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
                                )
```

Hosted Zone:

```
subdomainHostedZone = route53.HostedZone(
        self,
        'subdomainHostedZone',
        zone_name=subdomain,
        query_logs_log_group_arn=queryLogGroup.log_group_arn
    )
```

However, during deploy I recieve the error:

```
11:49:59 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Route53::HostedZone      | subdomainHostedZoneE712CA19
Resource handler returned message: "The ARN for the CloudWatch Logs log group is invalid. 
(Service: Route53, Status Code: 400, Request ID: {Rec-ID}, 
Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: {Rec-Token}, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

The outputted CF template shows the Hosted Zone as:

```
"subdomainHostedZoneE712CA19": {
"Type": "AWS::Route53::HostedZone",
"Properties": {
  "Name": "{FQDN}",
  "QueryLoggingConfig": {
   "CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn": {
    "Fn::GetAtt": [
     "logGroup68A52FBE",
     "Arn"
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 "DependsOn": [
  "CloudwatchLogResourcePolicyCustomResourcePolicyA1266CC5",
  "CloudwatchLogResourcePolicy687D24D9"
 ],
 "Metadata": {
  "aws:cdk:path": "awsStack/network-stack/subdomainHostedZone/Resource"
 }
},
```

Which appears to be correctly referencing the Log Group via Fn::GetAtt

I have tried adding the log group as a dependency, and attempted converting the log group to a L1 construct and then call getAtt manually, but the auto-generated CF seems to already be doing the same logic.

Comment: The log group must be in us-east-1.

Comment: No problem, I will make answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-logs.html):

> The log group must be in the **US East (N. Virginia)** Region.